# Qt c++ как вывести относительный путь от exe файла

Tags: c++, qt

Есть файл exe его путь D:/a/b/test.exe Рядом с exe файлом есть папка с файлами image/1.jpeg к примеру. Есть так же в папке image и другие папки c файлами. Хочу получать путь относительно exe т.е через QFile открываю файл 1.jpeg и хочу увидеть его размещение так ./image/1.jpg, это относительный путь от exe файла, а не абсолютный путь D:/a/b/image/1.jpg как выводит у меня щас щас. Как это сделать?

Comment: Получаете путь, с которого стартовала программа и добавляете к нему "../image/1.jpg". В чем проблема?

Comment: Мне нужно что бы при выводе пути файла путь отображался /image/1.jpg  т.е относительно exe файла, а не его полный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString appPath = "D:/programm";
    QString imgPath = "D:/programm/image/1.jpg";

    QDir dir(appPath);
    qDebug() << dir.relativeFilePath(imgPath);  //  image/1.jpg

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `QString appPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();`

Comment: Александр спасибо relativeFilePath то, что нужно!